# How to display all CPUInfo flags into alphabetical order?

Tags: linux, pipe

I need some help with the following:

> Write a single command that lists the features/capabilities of the CPU on your Linux machine, one per line, sorted alphabetically.
>
> The single command may use pipes and re-direction, but must not simply combine commands (e.g., using `;`).
>  An example of the first few lines of the contents is:
>
> ```
> 3dnewprefect
> abm
> aes
> apic
> ...
> ```

This is what I have so far, but it’s not sorting it alphabetically:

```
lscpu | grep -i flags | sort -d
```

Comment: You need to convert the single line of flags into a list of one line per flag, then sort that list.

Comment: Could you advise how best to do that.

Comment: You could use `sed`, which would enable you to get rid of the `grep` as well. Replace strings of spaces with newlines: `sed '/^Flags:/s/  */\n/g'`. You then need to remove the Flags line from the output.

Comment: I forgot you also need to remove all other lines from the output. You can do it in the same `sed` command by only printing the Flags line. This is accomplished with the `-n` option (don't print) and the `p` command: `sed -n '/^Flags:/s/  */\n/gp'`.

Comment: Thanks for showing us the command you tried. It’s also helpful to show the output you got from that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example, I added adding a newline for each space and then got rid of the *Flags:* heading and removed any empty lines like so:

`tr` translates any space to a newline so that we can then ultimately sort it later because `sort` works on a line by line basis

`egrep -v` does an inverted match, which removes the selection (Flags or empty lines)

```
lscpu | grep -i flags | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep -v '^Flags:|^$' | sort -d
```